# Can photon helicity change in interactions in QED?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, helicity

I'm wondering if a photon's helicity can change in QED. For example in Compton scattering could the exiting photon have a different helicity than the incoming photon?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can change since what is conserved is the total angular momentum of  photon + electron. So as long as the electron carries out an angular momentum such that it compensates the change of the helicity, it is allowed.

Comment: Indeed. In lower energies, cf the [Klein-Nishina formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein%E2%80%93Nishina_formula), you have helicity violation induced by the mass of the electron, so helicity is not a good number--even the helicity of the electron can flip, despite the vectorlike interaction preserving its chirality.